# How to create .mdb file?

Tags: python, hdf5, lmdb, zarr

I am new with zarr, HDF5 and LMDB. I have converted data from HDF5 to Zarr but i got many files with extension .n (n from 0 to 31). I want to have just one file with .zarr extension. I tried to use LMDB (zarr.LMDBStore function) but i don't understand how to create .mdb file ? Do you have an idea how to do that ? 
Thank you !

Comment: Is there a small snippet of code you can post? As per: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

@kish When trying your solution i got this error:

from comtypes.gen import Access
ImportError: cannot import name 'Access'

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples of using LMDB as a Zarr store in the [documentation for the LMDBStore class](https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/storage.html#zarr.storage.LMDBStore). E.g.:

```
>>> store = zarr.LMDBStore('data/group.mdb')
>>> root = zarr.group(store=store, overwrite=True)
>>> foo = root.create_group('foo')
>>> bar = foo.zeros('bar', shape=(10, 10), chunks=(5, 5))
>>> bar[...] = 42
>>> store.close()  # don't forget to call this when you're done
```

You don't have to do anything other than the above to create the .mdb file, it will be created automatically.

Comment: I will try it, Thanks a lot